# How to log in in site with API from another site

Tags: php, api, yii

We have a form:

```
<form class="" action="api.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="">
  <input type="text" name="password" value="">
  <input id="sub" type="submit" name="yt0" value="send">
</form>
```

which makes work the following code:

```
<?php
$url='http://......t.ru/client.php/site/login?r=post%2Findex';
$data=array('username'=>$_POST['username'], 'password'=>$_POST['password']);

$ch = curl_init($url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                     "Content-Type" => "application/json",
                                     "X-HTTP-Method-Override"=>"POST",
                                     "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"
                                ));
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
                    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
                    curl_close($ch);
                    var_dump($result);
```

the code has been sent to the following link: 
http://......t.ru/client.php/site/login
where there is the following code:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'htmlOptions' => array(),
    ));
    $hostinfo = Yii::app()->request->hostInfo;
    "$hostinfo/cabinet-info"
    ?>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model, ''); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <?php echo $form->label($model, 'username'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'username') ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <?php echo $form->label($model, 'password'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'password') ?>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row submit">
        <div class="span4 form-actions">
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Войти', array('class' => 'btn btn1-primary')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

but the registration process doesn't work.but API's code returns to HTML string

```
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://..........t.ru/assets/28dc1796/css/htmlwidget.css?v=201507161349" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://testdev.glogist.ru/assets/ede580e5/css/layouts.main.css?v=201507161349" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://.........t.ru/assets/ede580e5/css/pager.css?v=201507161349" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://testd'... (length=10429)
```

The question is what URL can I send a code to?
$url='http://........t.ru/client.php/site/login'; ?????????????????/